# Should the backend immediately download file selected by google file picker?

Tags: google-drive-api, download, google-picker

My backend application is an image processing service and it is resource intensive. Users send file to this service by selecting the target file using Google File Picker.  Sometimes the inbound files can be queued for days waiting to be processed. MY concern is that the file picker file uri and access token may expire. I want to know how what is that expiry time? Should the server download the file immediately or can it  wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented ; i stored the google file data along with authentication token. My code was able to download the file using the authentication token even after 24 hours.

So the answer is that the backend does not have to download the file immediately.